# Constructing Image From 2D Array in Java

Tags: java

I want to create the Image from 2D Array.I used BufferImage concept to construct Image.but there is difference betwwen original Image and constructed Image is displayed by image below

[image: This is My original image]

[image: Image After reconstruction]

I am using the following code

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

/**
 *
 * @author pratibha
 */

```
public class ConstructImage{
    int[][] PixelArray;
    public ConstructImage(){
        try{

        BufferedImage bufferimage=ImageIO.read(new File("D:/q.jpg"));
        int height=bufferimage.getHeight();
        int width=bufferimage.getWidth();
        PixelArray=new int[width][height];
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                PixelArray[i][j]=bufferimage.getRGB(i, j);
            }
        }
        ///////create Image from this PixelArray
        BufferedImage bufferImage2=new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
            for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
                int Pixel=PixelArray[x][y]<<16 | PixelArray[x][y] << 8 | PixelArray[x][y];
                bufferImage2.setRGB(x, y,Pixel);
            }


        }

         File outputfile = new File("D:\\saved.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(bufferImage2, "jpg", outputfile);


        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ConstructImage c=new ConstructImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: pixel array is 24 bit. where is alpha?

Comment: how we can defined Pixel Array? I have no Idea.Can u guide me

Comment: i looked at some structures and seen that it was r,g,b,alpha or alpha,r,g,b

Comment: you must be exchanging the alpha with red or blue.

Comment: so what is the solution? what should i do in my code?

Comment: does your image exactly fit in your array?

Comment: yes and where is alpha in my code?

Comment: i meant the last 8 bits of the every int element

Answer (score 8):

You get a `ARGB` value from `getRGB` and the `setRGB` takes a `ARGB` value, so doing this is enough:

```
bufferImage2.setRGB(x, y, PixelArray[x][y]);
```

From the API of [`BufferedImage.getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29):

> Returns an integer pixel in the **default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB)** and default sRGB colorspace.

...and from the API of [`BufferedImage.setRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Sets a pixel in this BufferedImage to the specified RGB value. The pixel is assumed to be in the **default RGB color model, TYPE_INT_ARGB**, and default sRGB color space.

---

On the other hand I would recommend you do paint the image instead:

```
Graphics g = bufferImage2.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(g, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

Then you wouldn't need to worry about any color model etc.

Comment: No problem :) Added a `Graphics.drawImage` example aswell.. maybe easier for you!

Comment: @Sumit you're forgetting to click the tick mark when people answer. You've done it here and in my answer earlier ;-) hint hint