# How do I create a black and white image from a 2D Array in Java?

Tags: java

This Python code

```
im_data = np.ones((100,100))
im_data[20:50,20:50]=np.zeros((30,30))
```

can generate a 2d array that could be used to create an image

```
plt.axis('off')
axi = plt.imshow(im_data, cmap='Greys')
```

[image]

I'm trying to do the same job with Java

```
    int[][] arr = new int[100][100];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j]=255;
        }
    }
    for(int i=20; i<50; i++){
        for (int j=20; j<50; j++){
            arr[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    ImageIO.write(arr, "jpg", new File("output.jpg") );
```

which outputs this error

```
no suitable method found for write(int[][],String,File)
        ImageIO.write(arr, "jpg", new File("output.jpg") );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not using the `arr` while creating the image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing Image From 2D Array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897297/constructing-image-from-2d-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIO` does not allow you to directly write a 2D array containing some numbers representing the darkness of pixels. You missed out a lot of information about the image here, like its color space.

One way is to create a `BufferedImage` and call `setRGB` for each element of the 2D array:

```
var image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 100 ; j++) {
        int rgb = arr[i][j] + (arr[i][j] << 8) + (arr[i][j] << 16);
        image.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
    }
}

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

If you have a *1D* array however, it is much easier. Just get the raster, and `setPixels`:

```
int[] arr = new int[10000];
Arrays.fill(arr, 255);
for(int i=20; i<50; i++){
  for (int j=20; j<50; j++){
      arr[i + 100 * j] = 0;
  }
}
image.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, 100, 100, arr);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

Also note that in the grayscale color space, 0 is black and 255 is white.